# Does virtual inheritance add overhead

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Suppose I have this class:

```
class A{
};
```

And this derived class:

```
class B : public virtual A{
};
```

And then nothing ever derives from `B`.

Does declaring `B` virtual add overhead that did not need to be there?

Comment: Why don't you make versions of your program with and without the virtual modifier, and see if the generated code is any different.

Comment: You probably meant,"does declaring `A` virtual".

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps because compilers are notoriously unpredictable for that sort of comparison.

Comment: Far as I remember, sometimes it's worse than dynamic casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think virtual inheritance may necessitate a small amount of extra overhead, although it may depend on how the compiler implements non-virtual inheritance.

Normal inheritance can be implemented by simply concatenating the members of the derived class to the base class (similar to having the base class as the first member of the derived class). Accessing members of the base class is a simple offset from the beginning of the object, just like accessing members of the derived class.

But with virtual inheritance, there has to be an indirection through a pointer. This allows all the classes that inherit virtually from the same base to have pointers to the shared data of the base class. So accessing a member of the base class requires first indexing to the virtual pointer, dereferencing that, and then indexing to the offset of the member.

This overhead has to be in the derived class even if there are no further derivations, because the compiler can't tell whether you might derive further in some other compilation unit that gets linked with this class. It's conceivable it could use some linker magic to link with different versions of the code depending on whether there's further derivation. But this means some overhead of its own in the form of two versions of the code for `B`.

For additional details, see 
[Memory Layout for Multiple and Virtual Inheritance](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html).

Comment: The link provided is very helpful for understanding virtual inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an indirection involved when accessing members of the virtual base class.

Comment: How can the compiler know if there's a second derivation? The second derivation could be in another compilation unit.

Comment: @Barmar devirtualization is hard, whether it's at LT or compile time.